# How can I use C# class and share it between 2 cshtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I want to port an ASP.NET Application (.aspx) to ASP.NET Web Site [Razor v3] (.cshtml) and I'm having troubles sharing a class variable between 2 pages.

Pretty easy example. If I have:

```
public class CompactDisk
{
    public string name;
    public string artist;

    public CompactDisk(string n, string a)
    {
        name = n;
        artist = a;
    }
}
```

I want to instance it in `_AppStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    CompactDisk cd = new CompactDisk("Abbey Road", "The Beatles");
}
```

And I want to use it in two different pages:

```
<p>@cd.name - @cd.artist</p>
```

What's the best way to share a class variable and access it from different pages?

Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new in Razor.

Comment: What do you mean by "class variable"? Do you mean instance of a type?

Comment: @Richard That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Create the instance in the controller and pass to the views as model .

Comment: Why not just use `public string name{get;set;};` pattern?

Comment: Don't create your models in your views. Thats not how it should be done in MVC. The Models (objects) should be created by the controller and passed to the views

Comment: MVC embraces the statelessness of HTTP (rather than hiding it). Therefore the way you handle state in an MVC web app is completely different to Web Forms. There is no "port" of "translation": you need to re-design the app for the different paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

If the class instance is not formally part of the ViewModel (i.e. is some "environmental information" like the users current logon info etc.) then create an instance in the Controller and set the value into the ViewBag. You can then access the ViewBag as a loosely typed dictionary of ambient values within your Razor page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new controller:

**Project/Controllers/CompactDiskController.cs**

```
public class CompactDiskController : Controller
{
    public CompactDisk Cd { get; }   

    public CompactDiskController()
    {
        this.Cd = new CompactDisk("Abbey Road", "The Beatles");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.Cd);
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View(this.Cd);
    }
}
```

2. Move Your model under

**Project/Models/CompactDisk.cs**

```
public class CompactDisk
{
    public string name;
    public string artist;

    public CompactDisk(string n, string a)
    {
        name = n;
        artist = a;
    }
}
```

3. Create new views under

**Project/Views/CompactDisk**

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Models.CompactDisk

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show from VIEW 1";
}

<h2>VIEW 1</h2>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.artist)
```

**List.cshtml**

```
    @model Project.Models.CompactDisk

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show from VIEW 2";
}

<h2>VIEW 2</h2>

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.artist)
```

Comment: in case of sharing, just use IOC container and inject it into constructor

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. But I have a problem, I can't add a Controller, I don't have that option anywhere, Do you know why? [Available Controllers](https://i.gyazo.com/380334aad02b6fc22961041e335a3dfb.png)

Comment: Well you need to know if you are developing ASP.NET MVC application or ASP.NET WebForms application. My example is asp.NET MVC. btw. there is no template for controller just add a new class and inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Comment: I'm developing ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3), and I can add only [Web API Controllers](https://i.gyazo.com/380334aad02b6fc22961041e335a3dfb.png) in VS2015

Comment: oki. Web Api Controller will not help you. it is use for RESTful response => there is no view involved. Views are used for MVC app. If you want to create Mvc controller you create a plain class and inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller. You might also find usefull "Scott Allen" excellent video course MVC 5 fundamental https://www.asp.net/mvc